# OpenCV + Tesseract: improving detecting text (credits) from complex image such as scenary

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I want to improve text recognition accuracy in somewhat complex image.

**I'm currently using following sample code:**

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp

**I'm trying to detect text from this image:**

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WFobUoRn6Ek/maxresdefault.jpg

(Note: It is similar kinds of footage I'm trying to handle)

---

**Result:**

There're many issues, but the biggest problem to me is small letters can be easily omitted or mis-recognized.

```
e.g.) 'i' became l
e.g.) 'in' became 'm'
e.g.) 'l' can be gone...
```

I think the problem is related to the resulted image from erFilter.
As this pic shows some small parts are already omitted at this point.

[image]

Please let me know if there's a good way to avoid such small parts omission.
Possibly some sort of preprocessing to the image?

---

**Note:**
I already checked following post, but the my target footage is similar to example of 'failure' case in his paper.

- [Detect white characters on black background using Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002966/detect-white-characters-on-black-background-using-tesseract/39309744#39309744)

Comment: If you have large amount of data use deep learning.

Comment: if possible, mis-recognition can be reduced by: 1. gather all potential ambiguous things like i=l, O=0, etc. 2. in your current image, spot all those ambiguous things. 3. find from a dictionary and context: try to find the most likely version. For example it is unlikely that the word is "TRALNING" but more likely to be "TRAINING". Yes, that's a lot of work... In special tasks (like ANPR-redetection) it might be enough to just replace all ambiguous things by a single fixed thing.

Comment: You can pre-process your image like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601528/how-to-split-noise-and-text-from-the-image-for-preprocessing-of-ocr