# Extracting part of image based on another mask tensor/image

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I need to segment out tables from an image. For this, I have the table mask for the given image based on which I need to extract the table from the image.
Here is the code for getting the masks :

```
# getting the predictions
table_mask_pred, col_mask_pred = tablenet.predict(image)
# getting the argmax values and expanding the dimensionality
table_mask_pred = tf.argmax(table_mask_pred, axis=-1)
table_mask_pred = table_mask_pred[..., tf.newaxis][0]
col_mask_pred = tf.argmax(col_mask_pred, axis=-1)
col_mask_pred = col_mask_pred[..., tf.newaxis][0]
```

Here is the original image, the mask for the columns in the image and the mask for the table
[image: Masks for the image]

I now want to use this table mask to extract the table from the image. The strategy that I am using right now is something like this:

1. Multiply the table mask and the image element-wise to get the table out.
2. Multiply the final image with 255 to get the pixel values back in the range 0-255.

However, this gives me the following image:

[image: Filtered image]

But, I want the filtered image to have a white background and not be so dark since I will be using the filtered image to extract the table contents using OCR.
How do I go about doing that?

Comment: OCR should be pretty independent of your background color

Comment: So even if I do OCR on the mask I'm getting, the results would be fine? If that is the case then my problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OCR is independent of background color,you can find the paper [here](http://www.m.cs.osakafu-u.ac.jp/cbdar2007/proceedings/papers/O1-1.pdf). Take a look at similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/39309744/14290244.